# Extract information from RTF file in ksh script

Tags: ksh

We have a few RTF files containing data that we need to extract and we seek automation in extract it:

I need to search for first occurrence of `<?for-each:APXINDTL?>` and should get APXINDTL to variable. For example:

```
<?for-each:APXINDTL?>
LOBCODE=APXINDTL
```

Note: The extraction operations shouldn't cause any change to the relevant RTF file.

The following is RTF file partial data which opened via a text editor:

```
{\rtf1\adeflang1025\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\adeff0\deff0\stshfdbch11\stshfloch0\stshfhich0\stshfbi0\deflang1036\deflangfe1041{\fonttbl{\f0\froman\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 02020603050405020304}Times New Roman{\*\falt Times};}{\f11\fmodern\fcharset128\fprq1{\*\panose 02020609040205080304}MS Mincho{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}
{\f36\fswiss\fcharset0\fprq2{\*\panose 020b0604030504040204}Tahoma;}{\f37\fmodern\fcharset128\fprq1{\*\panose 02020609040205080304}@MS Mincho;}{\f43\froman\fcharset238\fprq2 Times New Roman CE{\*\falt Times};}
{\f44\froman\fcharset204\fprq2 Times New Roman Cyr{\*\falt Times};}{\f46\froman\fcharset161\fprq2 Times New Roman Greek{\*\falt Times};}{\f47\froman\fcharset162\fprq2 Times New Roman Tur{\*\falt Times};}
{\f48\fbidi \froman\fcharset177\fprq2 Times New Roman (Hebrew){\*\falt Times};}{\f49\fbidi \froman\fcharset178\fprq2 Times New Roman (Arabic){\*\falt Times};}{\f50\froman\fcharset186\fprq2 Times New Roman Baltic{\*\falt Times};}
{\f51\froman\fcharset163\fprq2 Times New Roman (Vietnamese){\*\falt Times};}{\f155\fmodern\fcharset0\fprq1 MS Mincho Western{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}{\f153\fmodern\fcharset238\fprq1 MS Mincho CE{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}
{\f154\fmodern\fcharset204\fprq1 MS Mincho Cyr{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}{\f156\fmodern\fcharset161\fprq1 MS Mincho Greek{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}{\f157\fmodern\fcharset162\fprq1 MS Mincho Tur{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}
{\f160\fmodern\fcharset186\fprq1 MS Mincho Baltic{\*\falt ?l?r ??\'81\'66c};}{\f403\fswiss\fcharset238\fprq2 Tahoma CE;}{\f404\fswiss\fcharset204\fprq2 Tahoma Cyr;}{\f406\fswiss\fcharset161\fprq2 Tahoma Greek;}{\f407\fswiss\fcharset162\fprq2 Tahoma Tur;}
{\f408\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset177\fprq2 Tahoma (Hebrew);}{\f409\fbidi \fswiss\fcharset178\fprq2 Tahoma (Arabic);}{\f410\fswiss\fcharset186\fprq2 Tahoma Baltic;}{\f411\fswiss\fcharset163\fprq2 Tahoma (Vietnamese);}
{\f412\fswiss\fcharset222\fprq2 Tahoma (Thai);}{\f415\fmodern\fcharset0\fprq1 @MS Mincho Western;}{\f413\fmodern\fcharset238\fprq1 @MS Mincho CE;}{\f414\fmodern\fcharset204\fprq1 @MS Mincho Cyr;}{\f416\fmodern\fcharset161\fprq1 @MS Mincho Greek;}
{\f417\fmodern\fcharset162\fprq1 @MS Mincho Tur;}{\f420\fmodern\fcharset186\fprq1 @MS Mincho Baltic;}}{\colortbl;\red0\green0\blue0;\red0\green0\blue255;\red0\green255\blue255;\red0\green255\blue0;\red255\green0\blue255;\red255\green0\blue0;
\red255\green255\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;\red0\green0\blue128;\red0\green128\blue128;\red0\green128\blue0;\red128\green0\blue128;\red128\green0\blue0;\red128\green128\blue0;\red128\green128\blue128;\red192\green192\blue192;\red153\green0\blue0;
\red255\green255\blue255;\red51\green102\blue255;}{\stylesheet{\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs24\lang1036\langfe1041\loch\f0\hich\af0\dbch\af11\cgrid\langnp1036\langfenp1041 \snext0 Normal;}{\*\cs10 \additive \ssemihidden Default Paragraph Font;}{\*
\ts11\tsrowd\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tblind0\tblindtype3\tscellwidthfts0\tsvertalt\tsbrdrt\tsbrdrl\tsbrdrb\tsbrdrr\tsbrdrdgl\tsbrdrdgr\tsbrdrh\tsbrdrv 
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\loch\f0\hich\af0\dbch\af11\cgrid\langnp1024\langfenp1024 \snext11 \ssemihidden Normal Table;}{\*\ts15\tsrowd
\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10 
\trftsWidthB3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tblind0\tblindtype3\tscellwidthfts0\tsvertalt\tsbrdrt\tsbrdrl\tsbrdrb\tsbrdrr\tsbrdrdgl\tsbrdrdgr\tsbrdrh\tsbrdrv 
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs20\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\loch\f0\hich\af0\dbch\af11\cgrid\langnp1024\langfenp1024 \sbasedon11 \snext15 \styrsid12592315 
Table Grid;}{\*\cs16 \additive \rtlch\fcs1 \af0 \ltrch\fcs0 \cf17 \sbasedon10 \styrsid7888090 t1;}}{\*\rsidtbl \rsid68623\rsid93330\rsid142644\rsid155313\rsid264633\rsid332799\rsid395766\rsid403452\rsid552508\rsid658548\rsid752845\rsid1005327\rsid1069147
\rsid1128813\rsid1132924\rsid1259231\rsid1263278\rsid1265937\rsid1277887\rsid1389294\rsid1530811\rsid1992641\rsid1992983\rsid2060146\rsid2305827\rsid2307951\rsid2376273\rsid2390373\rsid2642557\rsid2643661\rsid2710428\rsid3037929\rsid3154780\rsid3165240
\rsid3281729\rsid3372746\rsid3547853\rsid3737551\rsid3741507\rsid3753885\rsid3829847\rsid4072213\rsid4226491\rsid4288612\rsid4616716\rsid4854419\rsid4924650\rsid5053770\rsid5254552\rsid5258838\rsid5340043\rsid5404475\rsid6044786\rsid6102238\rsid6112804
\rsid6123976\rsid6163342\rsid6175147\rsid6176396\rsid6308330\rsid6711426\rsid6835337\rsid6846292\rsid6970981\rsid7105696\rsid7110264\rsid7151052\rsid7223101\rsid7232350\rsid7235566\rsid7275561\rsid7408942\rsid7501061\rsid7696868\rsid7811265\rsid7888090
\rsid7944819\rsid8063473\rsid8132570\rsid8147290\rsid8153787\rsid8155155\rsid8201906\rsid8277229\rsid8328412\rsid8473648\rsid8731090\rsid8743219\rsid8792426\rsid8936820\rsid8996299\rsid9178122\rsid9527975\rsid9586581\rsid9640140\rsid9650079\rsid9723997
\rsid9922356\rsid9962332\rsid9975339\rsid9977927\rsid10179720\rsid10237241\rsid10240078\rsid10245831\rsid10254799\rsid10361269\rsid10507318\rsid10619503\rsid10712085\rsid10713024\rsid10831958\rsid11018322\rsid11083764\rsid11218957\rsid11540745
\rsid11546310\rsid11750115\rsid11805579\rsid11809863\rsid11826673\rsid11875358\rsid11882404\rsid11994392\rsid12005958\rsid12076017\rsid12131149\rsid12197000\rsid12332670\rsid12534999\rsid12592315\rsid12740964\rsid12795344\rsid12979432\rsid13117260
\rsid13122474\rsid13177707\rsid13181432\rsid13637823\rsid13648701\rsid13767565\rsid13770139\rsid13847229\rsid14100348\rsid14107631\rsid14162819\rsid14170956\rsid14311039\rsid14314535\rsid14575510\rsid14580414\rsid14616762\rsid15143013\rsid15364511
\rsid15667675\rsid15823145\rsid15928357\rsid16085770\rsid16124471\rsid16277686\rsid16319244\rsid16410490\rsid16538325\rsid16584785\rsid16647549}{\*\generator Microsoft Word 10.0.6835;}{\info{\title GL - Journals General (180 char)}{\author essilor}
{\operator essilor}{\creatim\yr2007\mo12\dy3\hr16\min52}{\revtim\yr2008\mo2\dy22\hr9\min58}{\version16}{\edmins18}{\nofpages2}{\nofwords437}{\nofchars2404}{\*\company ESSILOR}{\nofcharsws2836}{\vern16393}{\*\password 00000000}}{\*\xmlnstbl }
\paperw16838\paperh11906\margl1418\margr1418\margt1418\margb1418\gutter0\ltrsect \deftab708\widowctrl\ftnbj\aenddoc\hyphhotz425\grfdocevents0\noxlattoyen\expshrtn\noultrlspc\dntblnsbdb\nospaceforul\formshade\horzdoc\dgmargin\dghspace180\dgvspace180
\dghorigin1418\dgvorigin1418\dghshow1\dgvshow1\jexpand\viewkind4\viewscale65\pgbrdrhead\pgbrdrfoot\splytwnine\ftnlytwnine\htmautsp\nolnhtadjtbl\useltbaln\alntblind\lytcalctblwd\lyttblrtgr\lnbrkrule\nobrkwrptbl\snaptogridincell\allowfieldendsel\wrppunct
\asianbrkrule\rsidroot11805579 \fet0{\*\wgrffmtfilter 013f}\ltrpar \sectd \ltrsect\lndscpsxn\linex0\headery709\footery709\colsx708\endnhere\sectlinegrid360\sectdefaultcl\sectrsid2710428\sftnbj {\*\pnseclvl1\pnucrm\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang 
{\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl2\pnucltr\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl3\pndec\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta .}}{\*\pnseclvl4\pnlcltr\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl5
\pndec\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl6\pnlcltr\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl7\pnlcrm\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl8
\pnlcltr\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}{\*\pnseclvl9\pnlcrm\pnqc\pnstart1\pnindent720\pnhang {\pntxtb (}{\pntxta )}}\pard\plain \ltrpar
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid9962332 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs24\lang1036\langfe1041\loch\af0\hich\af0\dbch\af11\cgrid\langnp1036\langfenp1041 {\rtlch\fcs1 
\ab\af36\afs32 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f36\fs32\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid4616716 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 AP}{\rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af36\afs32 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f36\fs32\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid5254552\charrsid15143013 
\hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36  - Discoun\hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 t}{\rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af36\afs32 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f36\fs32\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid3741507 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 s}{\rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af36\afs32 \ltrch\fcs0 
\b\f36\fs32\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid5254552\charrsid15143013 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36  Taken and Lost Report}{\rtlch\fcs1 \ab\af36\afs32 \ltrch\fcs0 \b\f36\fs32\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid8277229\charrsid15143013 
\par }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid5254552\charrsid15143013 
\par }{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid5254552\charrsid15143013 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36  FORMTEXT }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid3741507 {\*\datafield 0001000000000000000011666f722d6561636820415058494e44544c0000000000153c3f666f722d656163683a415058494e44544c3f3e0000000000}{\*\formfield{\fftype0\ffownstat\fftypetxt0{\*\ffdeftext 
for-each APXINDTL}{\*\ffstattext <?for-each:APXINDTL?>}}}}}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\noproof\langnp2057\insrsid5254552\charrsid15143013 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 for-each APXINDTL}}}\sectd \ltrsect
\lndscpsxn\linex0\headery709\footery709\colsx708\endnhere\sectlinegrid360\sectdefaultcl\sectrsid2710428\sftnbj {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11882404\charrsid15143013 
\par }{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid332799\charrsid15143013 FORMTEXT}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid3741507 {\*\datafield 00010000000000000554657874310015435f434f4d50414e595f4e414d455f4845414445520000000000193c3f435f434f4d50414e595f4e414d455f4845414445523f3e0000000000}
{\*\formfield{\fftype0\ffownstat\fftypetxt0{\*\ffname Text1}{\*\ffdeftext C_COMPANY_NAME_HEADER}{\*\ffstattext <?C_COMPANY_NAME_HEADER?>}}}}}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\noproof\langnp2057\insrsid332799\charrsid15143013 C_COMPANY_NAME_HEADER}}}\sectd \ltrsect\lndscpsxn\linex0\headery709\footery709\colsx708\endnhere\sectlinegrid360\sectdefaultcl\sectrsid2710428\sftnbj 
{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11882404\charrsid15143013 
\par }\pard \ltrpar\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid10713024 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid15928357\charrsid15143013 
\hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 Report Date : }{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid10713024\charrsid15143013 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36  DATE \\@ "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" }
}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\noproof\langnp2057\insrsid10713024\charrsid15143013 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 15/11/2007 12:32:11}}}\sectd \ltrsect
\lndscpsxn\linex0\headery709\footery709\colsx708\endnhere\sectlinegrid360\sectdefaultcl\sectrsid2710428\sftnbj {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid15928357\charrsid15143013 
\par }\pard \ltrpar\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\itap0\pararsid9962332 {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid16319244\charrsid15143013 
Invoice Currency : }{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid16319244\charrsid15143013 FORMTEXT}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid3741507 {\*\datafield 00010000000000000554657874310014435f424153455f43555252454e43595f434f44450000000000183c3f435f424153455f43555252454e43595f434f44453f3e0000000000}
{\*\formfield{\fftype0\ffownstat\fftypetxt0{\*\ffname Text1}{\*\ffdeftext C_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE}{\*\ffstattext <?C_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE?>}}}}}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\noproof\langnp2057\insrsid16319244\charrsid15143013 C_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE}}}\sectd \ltrsect
\lndscpsxn\linex0\headery709\footery709\colsx708\endnhere\sectlinegrid360\sectdefaultcl\sectrsid2710428\sftnbj {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid15823145\charrsid1992641 
\par }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid16319244 
\par }\trowd \irow0\irowband0\ltrrow\ts15\trgaph70\trrh624\trleft-108\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10 
\trftsWidth3\trwWidth22009\trftsWidthB3\trftsWidthA3\trpaddl108\trpaddr108\trpaddfl3\trpaddft3\trpaddfb3\trpaddfr3\tbllkhdrrows\tbllklastrow\tbllkhdrcols\tbllklastcol\tblind0\tblindtype3 \clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone 
\clbrdrr\brdrnone \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth4503\clshdrawnil \cellx4395\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone \clbrdrr\brdrnone \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1275\clshdrawnil \cellx5670\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl
\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone \clbrdrr\brdrnone \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth2409\clshdrawnil \cellx8079\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone \clbrdrr\brdrnone \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1377\clshdrawnil \cellx9456\clvertalt
\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone \clbrdrr\brdrnone \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1113\clshdrawnil \cellx10569\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone \clbrdrr\brdrnone 
\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1134\clshdrawnil \cellx11703\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrnone \clbrdrl\brdrnone \clbrdrb\brdrnone \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1290\clshdrawnil \cellx12993\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl
\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1290\clcbpatraw19 \cellx14283\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 
\clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1290\clcbpatraw19 \cellx15573\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1290\clcbpatraw19 \cellx16863\clvertalt
\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1276\clcbpatraw19 \cellx18139\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr
\brdrs\brdrw10 \clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1254\clcbpatraw19 \cellx19393\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1254\clcbpatraw19 \cellx20647
\clvertalt\clbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \clbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \clcbpat19\cltxlrtb\clftsWidth3\clwWidth1254\clcbpatraw19 \cellx21901\pard\plain \ltrpar
\ql \li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid14100348\yts15 \rtlch\fcs1 \af0\afs24\alang1025 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs24\lang1036\langfe1041\loch\af0\hich\af0\dbch\af11\cgrid\langnp1036\langfenp1041 {\rtlch\fcs1 
\af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid1992641 \cell \cell }\pard \ltrpar\qc \li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid14100348\yts15 {\rtlch\fcs1 
\af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid1992641 \cell \cell \cell }\pard \ltrpar\qc \li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\tx742\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid14100348\yts15 {
\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid1992641 \cell }\pard \ltrpar\qc \li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid14100348\yts15 {\rtlch\fcs1 
\af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid1992641 \cell }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 Currency}{
\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid1992641 \cell \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 Inv. Amount\cell \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 Discount Taken\cell }{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid11826673 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 Discount Loss\cell }\pard \ltrpar\qc \li0\ri0\widctlpar\intbl\wrapdefault\aspalpha\aspnum\faauto\adjustright\rin0\lin0\pararsid10245831\yts15 {
\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid11826673 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 Inv. Amount (}{\field\flddirty{\*\fldinst {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 
\fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid11826673 FORMTEXT}{\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\cf8\lang2057\langfe1041\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\langnp2057\insrsid3741507 {\*\datafield 
00010000000000000554657874310014435f424153455f43555252454e43595f434f44450000000000183c3f435f424153455f43555252454e43595f434f44453f3e0000000000}{\*\formfield{\fftype0\ffownstat\fftypetxt0{\*\ffname Text1}{\*\ffdeftext C_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE}{\*\ffstattext 
<?C_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE?>}}}}}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \fs20\cf8\lang1024\langfe1024\loch\af36\hich\af36\dbch\af0\noproof\langnp2057\insrsid11826673\charrsid11826673 C_BASE_CURRENCY_CODE}}}\sectd \ltrsect
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `unrtf` and parsing the resulting text:

```
variable=$( unrtf --text file.rtf | sed -n '/^for-each/{s/^[^ ]* //p;q}' )
```

With the example given, this sets the value of the variable to the string `APXINDTL`.

The `sed` command will locate the first line (only) that starts with `for-each` and remove everything up to and including the space.  The rest of the line is assigned to the variable.

Comment: Glad you understand what's being asked.

Comment: @roaima The question follows the same pattern as their previous ones.

Comment: I need to search for first occurrence of <?for-each:APXINDTL?>.
 for-each will be present in the file many times. but we should pick the first occurrence only.

Comment: @ArunGoWdA I have fixed that now.

Comment: for-each will be reapedted many times with different tag.

for example below line have for-each 3 times.

I need to take first occurrence of the  <?for-each:APXINDTL?> this. not just "for-each".


for-each APXINDTL}{\*\ffstattext <?for-each:APXINDTL?>}}}}}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \ltrch\fcs0 \f36\fs20\lang1024\langfe1024\noproof\langnp2057\insrsid5254552\charrsid15143013 \hich\af36\dbch\af11\loch\f36 for-each APXINDTL}}}\sectd \ltrsect

Comment: @ArunGoWdA Sorry, I don't understand RTF very well. Could you please describe with words what you want to say?

Comment: I have updated. did you understand now?

Comment: @ArunGoWdA Does my updated solution not work?

Comment: and also when try to run the command it says: unrtf: command not found

Should we install this if so, what the version.

Comment: @ArunGoWdA You should install the most recent version available for you Unix.  I'm using version 0.21.9 here.

Comment: In the RTF file. "for-each" will present be in many time like;  sample data: for-each APXINDTL}{\*\ffstattext <?for-each:APXINDTL?>}}}}}{\fldrslt {\rtlch\fcs1 \af36\afs20 \lt ad so on....   In this I need to extract the first occurrence value of the which is written in the  "<?for-each:APXINDTL?> "

Comment: @ArunGoWdA Yes, I understand. This is what my solution does, after filtering the RTF file through `unrtf` to make it parsable.